# Will my situation allow me to retain my Windows license on this computer? Just in case I mess something up

Tags: uefi, windows-10, 18.10, iso, oem

I want to switch my computer to Ubuntu. I already have my bootable USB drive ready, which works just fine in live mode. I am currently a Windows user and I would like to retain my Windows license (OEM) in case I want to switch this laptop back to Windows. Since I only have an OEM license, the product key is embedded into the BIOS/UEFI firmware.

My question is: if I now erase my hard drive and install Ubuntu, but then decide to install Windows again (I already have an ISO image on another USB), will it recognize my OEM license and let me reinstall Windows?

Comment: You have tagged an EOL release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.10 reached *end-of-life* long ago (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/07/19/ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish-end-of-life-reached-on-july-18-2019/), and it's upgrade path to 19.04 is also gone (19.04 is now EOL too, users of it *release-upgraded* to 19.10 awhile back), so use a supported release of Ubuntu, and LTS or *long-term-support* releases if you don't like 6-9 month *release-upgrades*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The next microsoft thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/installing-windows-back-after-ubuntu/0dab3973-072d-410c-991b-ccb7d26119d7) answers your question:

Question:

> I recently Installed ubuntu on my laptop and cleared the disc on my pc
>   when doing so. Microsoft account still has my laptop listed in the
>   devices page.
>
> Is there any way of Installing windows 10 back without buying it?

Answer:

> Since your laptop is still listed under Devices in your Microsoft
>   account, you can perform a clean install or reinstall Windows 10
>   without the need of paying for it. This ensures a fresh copy of the
>   operating system. See this Forum Article by Greg Carmack - Windows MVP
>   for instructions and more information. Note that doing a clean install
>   will delete all data on your PC.